# C++ GUI Condition for if statement always true

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow

I created a simple login program in C++ GUI but for some reason the condition that makes the if statement true is always true no matter what. I've looked at a bunch of times now and I really don't know whats ccausing this, any input would be appreciated.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}



void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString username, password;
    username=ui->lineEdit->text();
    password=ui->lineEdit_2->text();

    truee=0;

    if (username=="Brandan")
    {
        truee=1;
    }

    if (password=="ABC123")
    {
        truee=truee+1;
    }

    if(truee=2)
    {
        ui->label->setText("Login succesful");
    }
    else
    {
        ui->label->setText("Failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: A simple typo: comparison is `==` not `=`. Enable compiler warnings to catch this error.

Comment: Wow cant believe I didn't catch that thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if(truee=2)` has to be changed to `if(truee==2)`